# Stacked div background img is black

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Issue with viewing stacked background image. All images are black. Animation works however no image is presented see code in snippet while html not loaded just indicated div that are effecting. The code should have the result as here https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/index4.html  however we have the effect easy enough but the img is black. I have tried several combinations of inline background image calls as well as in CSS still img is not showing any thoughts or inheritance I may be missing that is effecting this please let me know. Full code can be given upon request

```js
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
( function( $ ) {
 
 $.fn.hoverfold = function( args ) {

  this.each( function() {
  
   $( this ).children( '.view' ).each( function() {
   
    var $item  = $( this ),
     img  = $item.children( 'img' ).attr( 'src' ),
     struct = '<div class="slice s1">';
      struct +='<div class="slice s2">';
       struct +='<div class="slice s3">';
        struct +='<div class="slice s4">';
         struct +='<div class="slice s5">';
         struct +='</div>';
        struct +='</div>';
       struct +='</div>';
      struct +='</div>';
     struct +='</div>';
     
    var $struct = $( struct );
    
    $item.find( 'img' ).remove().end().append( $struct ).find( 'div.slice' ).css( 'background-image', 'url(' + img + ')' ).prepend( $( '<span class="overlay" ></span>' ) );
    
   } );
   
  });

 };

} )( jQuery );
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 General Style
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.section {
  padding: 30px 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.section-white {
  background: #FFF;
}
.section-dark {
  background: #151515;
}
.section-dark h3 {
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:200;
}
.section .container:first-child h1,
.section .container:first-child h2,
.section .container:first-child h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.input-micro {
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(79, 141, 179, 0.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
  /* IE6-9 */

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(79, 141, 179, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(79, 141, 179, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(79, 141, 179, 0.6);
  color: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(79, 141, 179, 0.6);
}
ul.no-list-style {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}
ul.no-list-style li {
  line-height: 28px;
}
div[class*="span"] {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
  -o-transition: all .4s linear;
  -ms-transition: all .4s linear;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Typography Style
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #535b60;
}
h1 {
  color: #53555c;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}
h2 {
  color: #53555c;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #53555c;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
h4 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #53555c;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
  color: #aec62c;
  outline: 0;
}
a:hover {
  color: #dcff21;
  text-decoration:none;
  outline: 0;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Services Style
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Multicolumn */
.service-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  color: 0 0 3px #999;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
.service-wrapper h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 10px 0 !important;
}
.service-wrapper p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.service-wrapper i {
 font-size:54px;
}
/* Row */
.service-wrapper-row {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.service-wrapper-row h3 {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.service-wrapper-row .service-image {
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.service-wrapper-row .service-image img {
  max-width: 80%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 7px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #999;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #999;
  color: 0 0 8px #999;
}




.view {
 width: 316px;
 height: 216px;
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 border: 8px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 
 -webkit-perspective: 500px;
 -moz-perspective: 500px;
 -o-perspective: 500px;
 -ms-perspective: 500px;
 perspective: 500px;
}
.view .slice{
 width: 60px;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 
 -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
 -moz-transform-origin: left center;
 -o-transform-origin: left center;
 -ms-transform-origin: left center;
 transform-origin: left center;
 
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 150ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 150ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: -o-transform 150ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: -ms-transform 150ms ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  
}
.view div.view-back{
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 background: #666;
 z-index: 0;
}
.view-back span {
 display: block;
 float: right;
 padding: 5px 20px 5px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.view-back span:first-child {
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.view-back a {
 display: bock;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
 position: absolute;
 right: 15px;
 bottom: 15px;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 22px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.view-back a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 border-color: #fff;
}
.view-back span[data-icon]:before {
    content: attr(data-icon);
    font-family: 'icons';
    color: #aaa;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 padding-right: 5px;       
}
.view .s2, 
.view .s3, 
.view .s4, 
.view .s5 {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(60px,0,0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(60px,0,0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(60px,0,0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(60px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(60px,0,0);
}
.view .s1 {
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.view .s2 {
 background-position: -60px 0px;
}
.view .s3 {
 background-position: -120px 0px;
}
.view .s4 {
 background-position: -180px 0px;
}
.view .s5 {
 background-position: -240px 0px;
}
.view .overlay {
 width: 60px;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.view:hover .overlay {
 opacity: 1;
}
.view img {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 0;
 -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ hover effect
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.view {
 perspective: 1050px;
}
.view div {
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view:hover .s2{
 transform: translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg);
}
.view:hover .s3, 
.view:hover .s5{
 transform: translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
}
.view:hover .s4{
 transform: translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
}
.view .s2 > .overlay {
 background: linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
.view .s3 > .overlay {
 background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
}
.view .s4 > .overlay {
 background: linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
}
.view .s5 > .overlay {
 background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
.view div.view-back{
 background: linear-gradient(left, #0a0a0a 0%,#666666 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section section-white">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h1>TOP SERVICES</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="grid" class="main">

                        <div class="view">

                            <div class="view-back">
                                <span data-icon="A">566</span>
                                <span data-icon="B">124</span>
                                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ag2r/5439506585/in/photostream">→</a>
                            </div>

                           <!-- <img src="img/portfolio/mobilem.jpg" />-->

                            <div class="slice s1" style="background-image: url(img/portfolio/mobilem.jpg); "><span class="overlay"></span>

                                <div class="slice s2" style="background-image: url(img/portfolio/mobilem.jpg); "><span class="overlay"></span>

                                    <div class="slice s3" style="background-image: url(img/portfolio/mobilem.jpg); "><span class="overlay"></span>

                                        <div class="slice s4" style="background-image: url(img/portfolio/mobilem.jpg); "><span class="overlay"></span>

                                            <div class="slice s5" style="background-image: url(img/portfolio/mobilem.jpg); "><span class="overlay"></span>
                                            </div><!-- /s5 -->

                                        </div><!-- /s4 -->

                                    </div><!-- /s3 -->

                                </div><!-- /s2 -->

                            </div><!-- /s1 -->

                        </div>

                        <div class="view">

                            <!-- ... -->

                        </div>

                        <!-- ... -->

                    </div> 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Please set up a working jsfiddle that shows the problem.

Comment: have trouble setting it up in the jsfiddle new to this type of format. reason on I have more than one bootstrap css page not sure how to include all without conflict

Answer (score 0):

I got a basic fiddle to work. It's probably a bad link to your images; that's the only thing I changed. Try adding a slash in front of `img`.

```
background-image: url(/img/portfolio/mobilem.jpg);
```

Comment: adding the " / " was tried already this effected the java script animation. so instead of a black block with animation we had no animation or black block where img is to go (similar to what you see in my jfiddle run code. I am thinking there is some CSS value that may be effecting the img but am unable to trace

Comment: Ok, but [here's my snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/gz72auq5/13/). The *only* thing I changed were the links to images.